# Problem with Truffle Console: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I´m having problem with the basic HelloWorld example coded in Solidity and managed with truffle with testrpc.

> pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
>
> contract HelloWorld {
>      uint public balance;
>
> function HelloWorld() {
>          balance = 1000;
>      }
>   }

[image]

```
>  truffle(development)>
> HelloWorld.deployed().balance.call().then(console.log) TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:30
>     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:35:29)
>     at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:67:17)
>     at TruffleInterpreter.interpret (c:\Users\whha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\lib\repl.js:128:17)
>     at bound (domain.js:280:14)
>     at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
>     at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:545:10)
>     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>     at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
>     at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:239:10) truffle(development)>
```

The problem looked similar to
[this thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11328/cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined?newreg=f8de615f36864aad88e89e665a215c28), but it does not solve my problem:

The contract is properly deployed and has a valid JSON document, I really don´t understand why I cannot access its members. The only one that return value is a constructor.

```
truffle(development)> HelloWorld.deployed().constructor
[Function: Object]
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If  you are running the latest version of Truffle (v.3.x), the way to call a function or variable in your contract has evolved a little bit according to the [Upgrading documentation](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/upgrading-from-truffle-2-to-3#contract-abstractions-deployed-is-now-thennable)

> In Truffle 2.0, your contract abstractions managed your networks in a
>   naive way, and added constructs like a "default network" that opened
>   up the possibility of using the wrong network artifacts and deployed
>   addresses at the wrong time. This provided a fancy and easy to use
>   syntax – i.e., MyContract.deployed().myFunction(...) – but it left
>   your code open to errors. Truffle 3.0 changes this syntax, where
>   .deployed() is now thennable, like a promise (see example below).
>   Similarly, this makes your contract abstractions seamlessly integrate
>   with EIP 190, Ethereum's package management standard. All of this is
>   for the better, but it means you'll have some changes to make all
>   across the board.

So in your case, if you want to call a function, you have to do this:

```
HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    return instance.balance.call();
}).then(function(balance) {
    console.log(balance);
});
```

Please refer to the [latest documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

you could also use :

```
HelloWorld.deployed().then(helloworld=> console.log(helloworld.balance.call()))
```

or

```
HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance){helloworld=instance})
```

then

```
helloworld.balance.call()
```

Comment: this answer is what you need to get the results from the console that they demonstrate here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jI1TuEaTro @BadrBellaj nice work :)

Comment: Even it calls a getter function I see an `Gas usage: 27034` on the `ganache` console, shouldn't be free to call `view()` functions? @Badr Bellaj♦