# truffle always says ".my_function is not a function"

Tags: truffle, testrpc

I'm trying to do my first basic smart contract, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jI1TuEaTro&t=1831s) popular HelloWorld tutorial.

However whenever I get to the part where I run a function in the truffle console, it is always telling me ".function_name is not a function".

For example, calling the default truffle MetaCoin getBalance function :

```
truffle(development)> MetaCoin.deployed().getBalance( web3.eth.accounts[0] )
TypeError: MetaCoin.deployed(...).getBalance is not a function
```

Am I calling the function incorrectly?
How should I be calling the `.getBalance` function in the MetaCoin example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK - this is essentially a [duplicate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11935/problem-with-truffle-console-cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined) - however I'm going to leave my question here because I've asked it very differently and I think others may ask the question this way too.

The answer is that truffle has changed the mechanism for calling functions since that video was made, the `deployed()` method returns a promise so you need to wait for that.
Here is the way to call the getBalance function now :

> truffle(development)> MetaCoin.deployed().then( function(instance) {
>   return instance.getBalance.call( web3.eth.accounts[0] )
>   }).then(function(balance) { console.log(balance) })

```
{ [String: '10000'] s: 1, e: 4, c: [ 10000 ] }
```

Source : [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11944/2040).

Comment: You can use `console.log(balance.toNumber());`

Comment: This isn't really a change in truffle. It's just that now they are using the latest version of web3 which uses Promises.