# Problem with truffle console : Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, testrpc

I have a problem when executing the code

`HelloWorld.deployed().balance.call().then(console.log)`

This error introduced: **Cannot read property 'call' of undefined**
This problem is similar to this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11935/problem-with-truffle-console-cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined) but it does not help on my case.

[image]
Thanks for your help!

My code is from [this turorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jI1TuEaTro)

```
contract HelloWorld {
  address public owner;
  mapping (address => uint) balances;
  function HelloWorld() {
    owner = msg.sender;
    balances[owner] = 1000;
  }
  function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] < _value) {
      return false;
    }
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    return true;
  }
  function getBalance(address _user) constant returns(uint _balance) {
    return balances[_user];
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of your contract HelloWorld?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a method called "balance" but "getBalance" with an address argument "_user", so you need to call it this way:

```
HelloWorld.deployed().getBalance.call('YOUR_ADDRESS')
```

Comment: I have tried this one. Unfortunately, it did not work. I added my code that you can better help

Comment: Test with: HelloWorld.deployed().getBalance.call('YOUR_ADDRESS') or  something like this should work: HelloWorld.deployed().getBalance.call(web3.eth.accounts[0])

Comment: I have tried this one too but it didn't work :(((

Comment: What do you got when you run : HelloWorld.deployed() ?

Comment: It seems that `HelloWorld.deployed()` works well. I got something like this
TruffleContract {
  constructor:
   { [Function: TruffleContract]
     _static_methods:
      { setProvider: [Function: setProvider],
        new: [Function: new],
...

Comment: Ok, please copy the result of: Voting.deployed().then(contract => { return contract.abi })

Comment: Did you mean `HelloWorld.deployed().then(contract => { return contract.abi })` ?

Comment: Yes sorry for the misspeling

Comment: This is the result of : HelloWorld.deployed().then(contract => { return contract.abi })

`[ { constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'owner',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function' },
  { inputs: [],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'constructor' },
  { constant: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'transfer',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
...`

Comment: please copy the full output to http://pastebin.com/ or something similar

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Z5iTCryx

Comment: This is so strange, could you also paste to pastebin the console output of this command : HelloWorld.deployed().getBalance.call(web3.eth.accounts[0])

Comment: This produces error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: Ok, last attempt and if doesn't work i really don't know: HelloWorld.deployed().getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0])

Comment: https://snag.gy/tD460A.jpg

Comment: Sorry but it does not work neither. Thanks